# Associating object names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to create a system that teaches people language. The user will type in a given sentence in the target language, and it will check to see if they've typed it correctly.

I want to give them a word bank for the current task (aka sentence) they are given.

The words in the word bank should be associated with the current task. In the image, the words boxed in green are part of sentence one, and red is part of sentence two.

[image]

To do this, I've put the tasks in an object. The keys are the task names, and values are the sentences.

```
var tasks = {
    "task1" : "Ni Hao. Wo Shi Dan.",
    "task2" : "Xie Xie. Bu Ke Qi."
}
```

The wordbank words are stored in an object... I'm trying to associate each wordbank set with the respective task name. But I also need to use the keys as the foreign language, and the values as the English. So I cannot use the `task name` as the key... So I'm having trouble associating the correct word bank to the given task by key name.

```
var words = {
    "task1" :
    {
        'Ni'    : 'you',
        'Wo'    : 'I',
        'Hao'   : 'good',
        'Shi'   : 'am'  
    },
    "task2" :
    {
        'Xie Xie' : 'Thanks',
        'Bu' : 'No',
        'Ke Qi' : 'Manners'
    }
}

var phrases = {
    "task1" :
    {
        'Ni Hao'    : 'Hello',
        'Wo Shi'    : 'I am'    
    },
    "task2" :
    {
        'Xie Xie' : 'Thanks',
        'Bu Ke Qi' : 'You are welcome'
    }
}
```

To move to the next task once the user has successfully typed in the first sentence, I've stored the task names in a taskQueue by task name...

```
var taskQueue = [];
taskQueue.push("task1", "task2");
var i = 0;

//Match the task name from taskQueue with the correct task
function task() {
    for (key in tasks) {
        return tasks[taskQueue[i]];
    }
}
```

My goal here is to match the current task name in the taskQueue with the appropriate key in the `words` object... but like I said, I'm already using the keys for this to store the Foreign language.

```
function bank() {
    $(".wordBank_Words").empty();
    $(".wordBank_Hint").empty();
    for (obj in words) {
        for (key in words[obj]) {
            if (words[obj] == taskQueue[i]) {
                $(".wordBank_Words").append("<li><b>" + key + "</b>: " + words[obj][key] + "</li>");
            }
        }
    }
    for (obj in phrases) {
        for (key in phrases[obj]) { 
            $(".wordBank_Hint").append("<li><b>" + key + "</b>: " + phrases[obj][key] + "</li>");
        }
    }
}
```

Here, once the user's input matches the task key's value (the sentence), `i` is incremented to move on to the next sentence:

```
function playerResponse(input) {
    bank();
    if (input == task()) {  
        i++;
        $("#responseVerify").html("Great job");
        document.getElementById('response').value = '';
    }
    else {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Keep going...");
    }
}
```

So how can I associate these keys by **name** so that the tasks object and wordBank object's keys match up for the given task?

Sorry if this is confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason your trying to do this all in javascript versus a more robust server side solution with a javascript front end? just trying to understand your requirements so i can help, i feel like an object store or an ontology would be a better fit for your app

Comment: @Matt617 No particular reason. I just wanted a quick mock up to see if it will work and get a concept across. Are you saying putting these words in a database would be better? Can you explain what you mean by objective store and ontology?

Comment: i think it would be a lot cleaner, then you would be writing queries for words or their meta-data as opposed to searching through objects iteratively. an ontology might be a bit much but mongDB would probably help you a bit ... jeeze even a mysql table would probably help

Comment: I'm racking my brains to see how I could use a db. I guess one table for sentences that query against a table of words? Then use jQuery $.get to provide feedback to the user? Also, do you know another way I can specify specific sentences to give to the user without actually providing a db entry for each sentence? I would rather dynamically grab vocab from the vocab table and arrange them per needs of the sentence.

Comment: that could work, or you could use similar JS objects in MongoDB and NodeJS and query across those documents using JQuery.AJAX

Comment: Why load all the calculations on the server for such a simple task. Sure, you could use it to set up a robust system, but sometimes all the developer and users need is a simple solution. Javascript would run in the client, and can be hosted on any server, with minimal requirements.