# Integrating Google Translate API into browser-based language game

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-translate

I'm creating a browser-based language learning game in Javascript. The user will be given specific English sentences that they will translate to Chinese using the help of a word bank (which provides the foreign language individual words and their associated English translations).

Someone suggested instead of creating my own database to store the words... I integrate Google Translate database since it allows me to dynamically translate text between thousands of language pairs.. (this was my original approach for word storage, btw: [Associating object names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911174/associating-object-names?noredirect=1#comment31392292_20911174)) I've never worked with the Google APIs, so I would appreciate guidance on the following:

- I thought most Google APIs were free. To integrate with their language db, do I need to pay?
  https://developers.google.com/translate/
- They only seem to provide some samples unrelated to the language software (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples). Any guidance on integrating it into my game would be helpful. I only found help on adding the widget to a website... but not using the database in my Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought most Google APIs were free.

Yes, most are. But Translate API isn't. The link you posted itself says "Google Translate API is available as a paid service". So of course you have to pay.

> Any guidance on integrating it into my game would be helpful

The internet is there to guide you only. Use it. Let us know when you face a problem. And you might want to look into [l10n and i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but this can be further reference to someone.

Follow the link below
[Google Language Translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/)

The above link will guide you to integrate google language translator into your website.

NOTE: **Your website must be hosted or live before you integrate this**